# getting push data in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I need some help in getting the inner push data.

in my app delegate file i have the following:

```
// Push notification received
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```

which results in the following:

```
Push notification received: [AnyHashable("aps"): {
Link = "http://www.website.com.dll?i.user8=App&id=374941&mobileOnly=true";
alert = "New survey";
}]
```

How would i go about in getting the value go LINK from data

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get push data as like below.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

     let dictPayload = userInfo as NSDictionary

     if let data = dictPayload.value(forKey: "aps") as? NSDictionary {
          let link = data.value(forKey: "Link") as? String
          print(link)
      }
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```